# Covariant version of the Coulomb gauge

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, covariance, gauge, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In curved spacetime, it is possible to define the covariant version of the Lorenz gauge, going from $\partial_\mu A^\mu =0$ to $\nabla _\mu A^\mu =0$ in some curved spacetime $g_{\mu \nu}$. What is the equivalent to that for the Coulomb gauge?

Comment: Making this a comment, since it's a guess, but $\nabla_i A^i=0$.

Comment: Would it still imply that $A_0=0$ ?

Comment: Coulomb gauge doesn't necessarily imply $A_0 = 0$ even in flat spacetime, since you can always apply a gauge transformation $A_\mu \to A_\mu + \partial_\mu \lambda$ with $\lambda$ a function of $t$ only.

Comment: $A_0=0$ is the Weyl gauge. You can have $A_0=0$ in the Coulomb gauge, but that's coincidental to $\rho=0$ everywhere.

Comment: The Coulomb gauge is impossible to specify geometrically in curved space without a distinguished temporal vector field, or something equivalent.

Comment: Thank you. I did have in mind the vacuum equations, but that is not the general case indeed. @Qmechanic, would specifying what the metric is (e.g. Schwarzschild) specify this temporal field? I am not sure what that is.

Comment: @N.E. - Is there a reason why the [Lorenz](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0204034), [Wigner-Covariant Coulomb Gauge](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9705156), [Bethe-Salpeter applied to the Wick-Cutkosky equation for the covariant Coulomb problem](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.27.2439), and "[Coulomb Potential from Lorentz Invariance in N Dimensions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10701-007-9117-9)" methods wouldn't provide a suitable covariant Coulomb?

Comment: Gauge fixing is useful for simplifying field equations. First you write correct equations for $A$ and then you figure out which combination can be treated as a gauge fixing (i.e., zero).